# php get_headers location

Tags: php, get-headers

how to use php get_headers only get location part?

```
var_dump(get_headers('http://www.google.com',1));
```

This return:

```
array(12) { [0]=> string(18) "HTTP/1.0 302 Found" ["Location"]=> string(21) "http://www.google.it/" ... }
```

Then I use

```
echo (get_headers('http://www.google.com',1)["Location"];
```

error: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '['` in this `echo` line

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
$headers = get_headers('http://www.google.com',1);
echo $headers["Location"];
```

Comment: thanks, this no error. BTW, do you think `$headers` more quicker or `curl - curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);` more quicker

Comment: @fishman didn't try to measure it but in the http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php user damolp says that the cURL is the fastest one to obtain the headers.

Comment: @fishman you're getting -1 for asking pointless question. both curl and get headers have to deal with network latency and none of them can speed it up.

Comment: for me lowercase worked only i.e echo $headers["location"];